# How to replace strongback across joists

Tags: flooring, attic, joists, structural

I am looking to floor my attic space and as part of the process, beef up my insulation.

Since my existing joists are 2x6s that span 12’9” with 16” spacing, I’m planning to sister the flooring area joists with 2x10s to both increase height and decrease deflection.

My problem is that the existing 2x6s have an “L” strongback that runs laterally on top of the whole of the attic. For me to fit the taller 2x10s under the strongback, I need to make cuts through it in numerous locations. What’s the best way to go about doing this?

My thoughts are to make my cut and install the first sister. Once the sister is installed, use a leftover piece of 2x10 to build a bridge between the newly installed sister and the neighboring joist. From there, repeat the process of removing a section of the strongback and replace it with a bridge one joist at a time.